# Populating Html.ActionLink() with a variable name results in an incomplete href

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Due to some unusual requirements I am getting the name of my controller while in my partial view and trying to populate an ActionLink with the controller name, like so:

```
@{
    var controllerName = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(); // controller name is "Office"

    @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", controllerName, null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
}
```

It is generating this HTML:

`<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Office">Login</a>`

whereas it should be generating this HTML:

`<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Office/Login">Login</a>`

The odd thing is that the link still directs to the `Login` action in the `Office` controller. What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Is `Login` the default action of the controller? That would explain why even the incomplete URL redirects to the `Login` action.

Comment: You must have a a route definition that is being matched with `defaults: action = "Login"`

Comment: Thanks to you both, I have this in my `RouteConfig.cs`:                 `defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`. I'm kind of surprised that it would direct to that default action even when I'm not in that controller though.